# Set bool value only when parameter is used Powershell

Tags: powershell, boolean, optional-parameters

I have an optional Boolean parameter

```
[Parameter(Mandatory=$false,Position=15)]
[bool]$MyBoolValue,
```

that I would like to set to my variable later in the code:

```
$SomeVariable=$MyBoolValue
```

but only if the parameter is set in the cmdlet

```
Do-MyStuff -Name blabla -MyBoolValue $false
```

if the cmdlet does not include the parameter

```
Do-MyStuff -Name blabla
```

`$SomeVariable` should remain unchanged (it may be false or true depending on other elements of the function)

I found this:

```
if($MyBoolValue.IsPresent)
  {
  $SomeVariable=$MyBoolValue
  }
```

but it is completely ignored (there is no `.IsPresent` property??)

Any advice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `$PSBoundParameters` auto variable:

```powershell
if($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey("MyBoolValue")){
    $SomeVariable=$MyBoolValue
}
```

Comment: You beat me to it because the ISE took too long to open. (I wanted to test to be sure I remembered correctly.) =)